# Удобный выпадающий список Select

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, html5

Интересует, как сделать удобный выпадающий список **Select**, чтобы было легко в нем найти элемент.
Во-первых, элементы выстроены в алфавитном порядке.

Во-вторых, как сделать, чтобы при вводе буквы список прокручивался на элементы, начинающиеся на эту букву?

Также думал сделать, что если пользователь из списка не может найти слова, он вводит его вручную (менять **SELECT** на **Input**).

У кого какие мысли по юзабилити Select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А использовать обычный `input type="text"` с параметром `list="browsers"`, а ниже прописать `datalist id="browsers"` не прокатит? Мне кажется, как раз для такого случая.

Comment: Вот пример http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_list.asp

Comment: Можете пример привести HTML?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/diefair/3e96fqzj/ - поробуй ввести Safari.

Comment: Инпут никак не закрывается? И можно ли сделать один option как selected?

Comment: Нет, input не имеет закрывающего тега.

Comment: Можно ли сделать один option как selected?

Comment: Наверное, нет.

Answer (score 1):

вот вам http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

кроссбраузерное решение

Comment: Я как раз таки это и использую. Только вот нужен изначально полный выпадающий список, а лишь потом ввода слова.

Comment: Смотри, если у тебя, к примеру, 10 записей, то я бы юзал обычный select и не парился - для легкости наыигации можно еще группы прикуртить к нему)  
autocomplete и вариант Diefair, по моему мнению, используют, когда реально выбор огромен и нужна быстрая навигация, и тут как бы само собой отпадает нужда вывода списка целиком - представь: у тебя 100 записей - их выводить списком-то не очень красиво ) ИМХО..

Comment: Можно ли сделать в нем, чтобы по клику на input выводился весь список?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), заодно можно свой дизайн select'а сделать

Answer (score 0):

Select 2 (ниже) или Chosen (ужа дал MasterAlex)

```
http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/
```